# MySQL simple database design for academy

Tags: mysql, database, erd

Hi I am trying to make a database for academy that offers courses , 
I have two tables that have many-many relation ship, 
which are:

```
 Student id(PK)
name
number
NationalID
absences
```

and the Second table is courses

```
    cid(PK)
    cname
   cpercentage
chours
type
```

so now according to the design rules i must create a third table for the relationship that has the both keys for student and course

```
 Enrolls
id
cid
```

now in mysql i inserted both of these columns as a child and got the reference from the 2 main tables ,
now my question is : is this table(Enrolls) will got modified by default whenever i add a course or student , or should i modify it by myself ?

thanks every body.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship, you have two main tables and a middle table which will make the relationship betwin those 2 main tables. One student can attend more than one course and one course can be attended by many students. The answer for your question si yes you have to insert also into the midle table which is Enrols.

Comment: so what is the point off adding the relationship in mysql ? 
thanks :)

Comment: for example if you want to see what are the student that atend the course X you need that table becouse that is the only table thet will tell you